# Is it noticeable if audio is inverted?

Tags: amplifier, audio

I'm looking at the LM4881 headphone amplifier. The amplifier uses an inverting OpAmp style set up.

What is the effect when audio gets inverted?

Will a difference be noticed or do we hear inverted audio all the time and never notice?

Should there be a second inverting stage to keep the audio the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's absolutely no difference if the audio signal is inverted or not.

You only get in trouble if you try to combine sources where one is inverted and the other is not, for example if you connect one speaker in reverse in a stereo system. Then the audio waves will cancel. This is usually immediately obvious.

Comment: Why isn't there any difference seen even when the waves are inverted? whats the reason behind it?

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaFarooq That's a question for physics or biology, too much to answer in a comment (and the wrong place)

Comment: okk sir thankyou. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have multiple outputs, some inverted and some not, you will never tell. With multiple outputs the reaction to this can be anything from an indistinct sense of "wrongness" all the way to mild nausea.